# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo-sqlite.so'

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, dynamic-library

I found these issues after updating *php5-sqlite* (previously it was working fine) :

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name in Unknown on line 0`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension in Unknown on line 0`

p.s : *so files* exist

Details :

1. OS : **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**
2. PHP : **PHP 5.6.15**

I have tried uninstalling (purge) and reinstalling PHP but the issues still remain.

I have tried commenting out **extension=pdo-sqlite.so** in **/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini**, but it says "**Driver not found**".

Please help...

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48614&edit=1 this may help

Comment: previously it was working fine, then after php5-sqlite update, this issues occured

Answer (score 1):

If you have built SQLite from source? Then, you forgot to enable Column metadata. Recompile SQLite with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Have fun using the cutting edge SQLite.

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata